# Can you code in the cloud?

Tags: cloud

I am developing a one hour science fiction TV drama for the networks about cloud-based programming.

The idea is that hundreds of thousands of programmers are working on creating a virtual Utopian world all at the same time. In this world they try and solve some of the worlds biggest problems.

It is this idea of a group of like minded individuals all trying to solve the same problems that drive the heart of the show and start to give the main character insights into what to do in the real world.

That is until a group of hackers start to turn the collective conscience and good will into something much more sinister. Is this idea at least "somewhat" possible?

Meaning can a large group of people could be all coding at the same time in the cloud on the same program?  Think of it like creating the code for new sections of World of Warcraft while also playing it at the same time.

If so what code language would be the most likely that they would use?  Hope this makes sense to everyone...

Comment: It's not like any TV dramas fact check anything technology-related anyway.

Comment: Good point, but I hate shows that are stupid and since I'm the creator and it is going to a big-time show runner that I actually respect, I want to have the chops to say that at least theoreticly my ideas are possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use a source code repository like Git or Subversion and a Continuous Integration tool like Jenkins, which allows you to build right after every push into the repo. Jenkins will build and test the code, and will deploy your virtual Utopian app world if everything was successful

You can also provide a context for the cloud talking about cloud technologies. Use an IDE on the cloud like [codenvy](https://codenvy.com/), use a cloud git repository to push this source code and a [Jenkins cloud service](http://www.cloudbees.com/jenkins) to build and to test it. The runtime environment could be also on the cloud.

You can show in your science fiction TV drama that everybody is coding everything on the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as long as they use svn or git and create separate branches.

As for what programming language.. The one you wrote.. It is your tv show.. U call it whatever..

Answer (score 0):

Seems interesting.
You can try the below mentioned link 
https://koding.com/
May be this will help you somehow

Comment: Thanks great to see it already is happening at least in some way!!